# get column index of hide column in extjs grid panel

Tags: extjs

I need to get column index of hide column in `extjs grid` panel

```
columnhide: function() {
            var cell = this.getEl().query('.x-grid-cell-inner');

            for(var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
            if (i%2 != 0){  // Instead of this i, want to change the style to none for the  hide column, so i need to get the column index of hide column in grid panel
                    cell[i].style.display= "none";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the columnhide listener:

```
columnhide: function(ct, column, eOpts) {
    alert(column.getIndex());
},
```

Alternatively, you could loop through the grid columns and check the isHidden() property on each column:

```
Ext.each(grid.columns, function(column, index) {
   if (column.isHidden()) {
       alert('column at index ' + index + ' is hidden');
   }
});
```

I have a test case set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/cCEh2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vd7f8/11   --- Here when i click col1/col2 to hide, inside columnhide function i want to get the column index of col1/col2 based on the checkbox unselection

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vd7f8/12/ - I've modified your example to show an alert with the index of the column you've just hidden.

Comment: i applied some style if the column is hidden, i want the same style to be applied if the property hidden is true for column

Comment: columnhide: function() {
         var cell = this.getEl().query('.x-grid-cell-inner');
         var collen = grid.columns.length;
         var i = 1;
          for (var y = i; y < cell.length; y = y + collen) {
             for(var x = 0; x < cell.length; x++) {
              if (x == y) {
                 cell[x].style.display= "none";
                  }    
             }  
            }
           }

Comment: header: 'SAMPLE VALUE',
            width: 240,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'SAMPLE VALUE',
            hidden:true, ------- For this column during first time page load above style of none is not getting applied. once i hide/show column it is working fine. Need the same functionality on page load also if the property hidden is true. Please help